# How save HTML form url with vebview Android 4.3+

Tags: android, html, webview

I need help. This code worked on Android 4.2 and below, but on Android 4.3 and above doesn't work. I need to get the source code from any url and save it to a custom file.

Why WebView? Because I need to save the code, which after login, and it is stored in cookies.

```
    class MyJavaScriptInterface   
        {  
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")  
            public void showHTML(String html)  
            {  
                try {
                      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                          openFileOutput("home_slider", MODE_PRIVATE)));
                      bw.write(html);
                      bw.close();

                }
                    // Connect to the web site
                      catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }  
        }  

        final WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv_hide);  
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
        browser.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(true);
        browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
        browser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");  
        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
            @Override  
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  {          browser.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");  
            }  
        });  

        /* load a web page */  
        browser.loadUrl("http://myurl.com");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add @JavascriptInterface annotation before your showHTML method declaration